# Making Favorite button in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

my task is to make favorite button with jetpack compose.

On my picture in top left corner I should put favorite icon.

I managed to make picture:

```
    Box(modifier = Modifier.height(200.dp)){
                Image(
                    painter = movie.picture,
                    contentDescription = "Something",
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                )
                ListItem (
                    trailing = {
                        if (movie.isCheckedOff != null) {
                        Checkbox(
    
    
                            checked = movie.isCheckedOff,
                            onCheckedChange = { isChecked ->
                                val newMovieState = 
                            movie.copy(isCheckedOff = isChecked)
                                onMovieCheckedChange.invoke(newMovieState)
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp)
                        )
                    }
```

This makes image and does logic for Checkbox ( I don't want to use checkbox). Should I have 2 images and then use one if button is true and another if false. I have problem with displaying favorite picture and then switching it on and off.

Image: [image: ""]

Comment: Post some images of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. That seems like a `Toggle Button`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this

```
@Composable
fun FavoriteButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color(0xffE91E63)
) {

    var isFavorite by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isFavorite,
        onCheckedChange = {
            isFavorite = !isFavorite
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            tint = color,
            modifier = modifier.graphicsLayer {
                scaleX = 1.3f
                scaleY = 1.3f
            },
            imageVector = if (isFavorite) {
                Icons.Filled.Favorite
            } else {
                Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder
            },
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }

}
```

You can change from `var isFavorite by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }` to states in ViewModel if you want to store favorite state for instance if this is in a LazyColumn.

Add transparent circle behind the button with

```
   Surface(
        shape = CircleShape,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(6.dp)
            .size(32.dp),
        color = Color(0x77000000)
    ) {
        FavoriteButton(modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp))
    }
```